# Rendering a pdf file from an html view to display it on a web page as a image preview

Tags: html, css, grails, groovy

I need to create a pdf preview that should be displayed on a web page as an image. The pdf file is just a simple report build on almost plain HTML. Essentially I had a problem with displaying checkboxes, now I replaced them with pics of checkboxes but the issue remains the same.
Here how I create the pdf report from my HTML view with help of groovy and grails:

```
def html = htmlRenderService.getReport(info)
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    HtmlImageGenerator htmlImageGenerator = new HtmlImageGenerator()
    htmlImageGenerator.loadHtml(html)
    BufferedImage bi = htmlImageGenerator.bufferedImage
    ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", out)
    byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray()
    String base64bytes = encoder.encodeToString(bytes)
    String src = "data:image/png;base64," + base64bytes
    out.flush()

def getReport(Info info) {
    return groovyPageRenderer.render(view: REPORT_VIEW,
            model: [info: info])
}
```

Then I send the src string to my view and render it as:`<img src="${src}" alt=""/>`

Then my checkbox pic looks like this: `<div style="/*style stuff*/ background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,LINK_TO_THE_IMAGE"></div>`

In the end, I received a picture of my pdf report rendered pretty well displaying as an image on my page, BUT without checkboxes. Here is the picture of one part of it:
[image]
And here is the same part but from the pdf document which I rendered all the same way, but just downloaded directed from my webapp:
[image]
Here is an example where I combined both options(input checkbox and image checkbox) and rendered it as an image:
[image]
So what could cause this issue? Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: I came across today to this comment under another issue with HtmlImageGenerator:

> HtmlImageGenerator seems to use a JEditorPane for rendering the HTML. Swing HTML support does not extend to the ability to render data images. It might be possible by digging into the HTMLEditorKit and changing the image loading element to support data images, but then you'd need to find a way to get HtmlImageGenerator to use the altered editor pane.

Seems that HtmlImageGenerator doesn't work well with images inside HTML files, but it's still unclear why it doesn't render checkbox inputs as well.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what you're looking at?

Comment: I have updated my initial post and added a few screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code you end up with after page load, check the chrome dev tools panel to see if the image has actually loaded correctly to the page which will tell you it's at least accessible to use. Then check if the url is output correctly to the div as the background-image. If it looks correct and there aren't related errors in the console, it is likely a css setting.

With background images, your container will need to contain content or else you will need to specify:

- `width`
- `height`
- a `display` setting
- `background-position`, and a
- `background-size`

If you can upload more info, I might be able to be more specific.